# Mockito mocking restTemplate.postForEntity

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock `restTemplate.postForEntity` method,

The actual method call is:

```
URI myUri = new URI(myString);
HttpEntity<String> myEntity ...


String myResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(myUri, myEntity, String.class);
```

What I have in my test class is:

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(URI.class), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);
```

This does not work; I have tried several other permutations with no success either. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

By this does not work I mean that the actual method is called and not the mocked method (so the desired result is not returned etc.)

Comment: _This does not work_ is not very informative.

Comment: Just an unsought comment: mocking this kind of classes is usually a bad practice. One of the good practices of TDD with mocks is to **not** mock classes you don't own.

Answer (score 13):

The following code works for me - 
`when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);`

Comment: How are you creating the response object? Can you provide the example?

Comment: private ResponseEntity<String> createPaymentConfirmationResponse(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("something");
    }

Comment: this is not working at all, not even compiling.  Cannot resolve method any()

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me
Firstly a resttemplate needs to be mocked in the test class

```
@Mock 
private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
```

Since ResponseEntity returns an Object create another method that returns the expected response wrapped in ResponseEntity

```
private ResponseEntity<Object> generateResponseEntityObject(String response, HttpStatus httpStatus){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
}
```

In your test case, you can now mock the expected response as follows

```
String string = "result";
when(mockRestTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any()))
        .thenReturn(generateResponseEntityObject(string, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: this is not working at all, not even compiling.  Cannot resolve method any()

Comment: hey Pixel, OP uses the Mockito framework where he uses a static import: import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the `postForEntity` method is final - you could use `RestOperations` instead of `RestTemplate` to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html). Then it would return mock response, no matter what [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) method or its overloading you use for `POST` call - `postForEntity`, `postForObject` or `exchange`.

For example:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class YourServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private YourService yourService;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }
    
    @Test                                                                                          
    public void methodWithPostCallTest() {   
        
        mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), 
          requestTo(new URI("post-method-url")))
          .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
          .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .body("mock-response-body")
        );                                   
                       
        String response = yourService.methodWhichExecutesPost();

        mockServer.verify();

        assertEquals("mock-response-body", response);                                                        
    }
}
```

More details: [Testing Client Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that you initialize the restTemplate as a mock in your tests

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
```

AND that this (mocked) rest template is the one being used in your actual method call. You could
have a setRestTemplate() method on your object, and you could use that to set the restTemplate:

```
 myTestObject.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
```

Mocks will **never** just call the original method, so if that's happening you can be pretty sure your actual method is not using a mock. (Real) mocks will either return what you told them to, or null.

Comment: What if you autowire TestTemplate in your service class?

Answer (score -1):

resttemplate returns  ResponseEntity

[Postforentity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api//org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) so something like ResponseEntitymyResponse=
restTemplate.postForEntity(myUri, myEntity, StringToReturn.class); where StringToReturn is whatever type to return (just String in your case)