# How to write mockito junit for Resttemplate postForObject method

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to post list of messages to the rest api. How to write mockito junit for the method postJSONData below:

```
public class PostDataService{

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private HttpEntity<String> httpEntity;

    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    private String resourceURL = null;

    public PostDataService(){
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    public void postJSONData(List<String> data){
    try
    {
    resourceURL = env.getProperty("baseURL") + env.getProperty("resourcePath");
    httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(data.toString(), httpHeaders);
    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(resourceURL, httpEntity, String.class);
    }
    catch (RestClientException e) {
            LOGGER.info("ErrorMessage::" + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.info("ErrorCause::" + e.getCause());
        }
    } 


}
```

Please help me how to write.

Comment: The question is: what do you want to test?

Comment: @Stefan Birkner: I want to mock the service and test the method postJSONData. In this scenario, the resourceURL consists of the actual service where I am making a post request by sending the list of messages in the body and see if I can capture the response status code. Do I need to use MockRestServiceServer in this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito mocking restTemplate.postForEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272391/mockito-mocking-resttemplate-postforentity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Mockito to:

- Create an instance of `postData` with mocked `RestTemplate` and `Environment`
- Set expectations on these which allow the ``postJSONData` call to complete
- Verify that the mocked `RestTemplate` is invoked correctly

The `postJSONData` method does not use the `restTemplate.postForObject()` response so the best you can do in terms of testing this method is to verify that `restTemplate.postForObject()` is invoked with the correct parameters.

Here's an example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PostDataTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Mock
    private Environment env;

    @InjectMocks
    private PostData postData;

    @Test
    public void test_postJSONData() {
        String baseUrl = "theBaseUrl";
        String resourcePath = "aResourcePath";

        Mockito.when(env.getProperty("baseURL")).thenReturn(baseUrl);
        Mockito.when(env.getProperty("resourcePath")).thenReturn(resourcePath);

        List<String> payload = new ArrayList<>();

        postData.postJSONData(payload);

        // it's unclear from your posted code what goes into the HttpEntity so
        // this approach is lenient about its expectation
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate).postForObject(
                Mockito.eq(baseUrl + resourcePath),
                Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),
                Mockito.eq(String.class)
        );

        // assuming that the HttpEntity is constructed from the payload passed 
        // into postJSONData then this approach is more specific
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate).postForObject(
                Mockito.eq(baseUrl + resourcePath),
                Mockito.eq(new HttpEntity<>(payload.toString(), headers)),
                Mockito.eq(String.class)
        );
    }
}
```

On a side note; `postData` is an unusual name for a class and the `postJSONData` method provided in your OP doesn't compile; it references `meterReadings` rather than `data`.

Comment: I tried this approach and facing the following error Wanted but not invoked Wanted but not invoked:
restTemplate.postForObject(
    "http://localhost:8080/updateOperation",
    <[test],{Content-Type=[application/json]}>,
    class java.lang.String
);Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Can you confirm - by debugging - that the instance of `RestTemplate` in use in `postJSONData` is **definitely** a mock?

Comment: This is working but what will be the scenario if I want to validate the respons status code after making a post request?

Comment: As things stand you do not return the repsonse code so it is not possible to verify it. If you reworked `postJSONData` such that it returned the response code then you could do somehting like this in your test: `String response = postData.postJSONData(payload); assertEquals(expectedResponse, reponse);`

Comment: Though, of course, since you are mocking the 'RestTemplate' asserting against it's return value is of limited usefulness.

Comment: Hi @glytching any suggestions for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780621/mockito-unit-testing-resttemplate Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just mock `postForObject` correctly:

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class YourServiceTest {
        
            @Mock
            RestTemplate template;
        
            @InjectMocks
            private final YourService srv = new YourService();
        
        
            @Test
            public void yourTest() {
                when(template.postForObject(anyString(),any(Object.class),eq(String.class)))
                        .thenReturn("xxxxxxxxxxx");
                assertEquals("xxxxxxxxxxx", srv.yourMethod());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wiremock](http://wiremock.org) to mock the server. It's a mocking framework specifically for this job.

Add following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add following rule to your test:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(); // default port is 8080
```

Then you should define your `baseUrl` and `resourcePath` properties in `application.properties` (or elsewhere). Remember, the server will be running on localhost.

After that you should mock HTTP response for resourcePath:

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(resourcePath))
            .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withBody(content)));
```

Then you can execute postJSONData method:

```
postData.postJSONData();
```

And finally, you can verify if a request to the server was correct.

```
verify(postRequestedFor(urlMatching(resourcePath))
        .withRequestBody(matching(expectedBody))
        .withHeader("Content-Type", matching("application/json")));
```