# How do I mock local OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a method:

```
public void putObj(Doc doc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = something.thatReturnsOAuth2RestTemplate(props);
                restTemplate.postForEntity(somethingElse.getUrl(), doc.toJSONString(), String.class);
                break;
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
                //do stuff in here
            }
        }
    }
```

And my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(OkHttp3TemplateUtil.class)
public class TestingClass {

@InjectMocks
private static MyService myService;

@Mock
private static Something something;

@Mock
private static Props props;

@Mock
private static OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
    public void testExceptionCaughtWhenThrownByRestTemplate(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(OkHttp3TemplateUtil.class);
        Doc doc = new Doc.docBuilder().setSomething("");

        when(something.thatReturnsOAuth2RestTemplate(props)).thenReturn(restTemplate);
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity("http://dummy.com", String.class, String.class)).thenThrow(HttpClientErrorException.class);
        myService.putObj(doc);
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, `thenThrow` never throws an exception.  The test passes never providing coverage for code after `catch`.  What am I missing here, I'm going mad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use matchers from Mockito.

In your case the 3 args for `restTemplate` are a bit confusing. The 1st is a `String` value so use `anyString()` to match it and mock out `somethingElse.getUrl()`, that code isn't in the example so not sure what it does but it must return a `String` and not be `null`. It looks like you want to match any string for the 2nd, with Mockito you need to use `anyString()` or `any()` if it is not a `String` to accomplish that. The 3rd is the actual value of `String.class` so again use `eq()`. Note, if any params are null it will not match. Also, it is easy to end up mocking out a different overloaded `postForEntity` if you're not careful.

For the `something.thatReturnsOAuth2RestTemplate`, you might be OK without a matcher. If the `Props` class has equals defined and both the test and production code values are equal. However, the example doesn't show this info, so I just added the `any(Props.class)` for that too.

```java
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;

@Test
    public void testExceptionCaughtWhenThrownByRestTemplate(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(OkHttp3TemplateUtil.class);
        Doc doc = new Doc.docBuilder().setSomething("");

                when(something.thatReturnsOAuth2RestTemplate(any(Props.class))).thenReturn(restTemplate);
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);
}
```

Comment: I get exactly the same result with the above code :(

Comment: What is the `OkHttp3TemplateUtil` stuff for? It doesn't appear in the production code

Comment: Apologies, `OkHttp3TemplateUtil ` = `something`.  I had missed it when renaming methods to post on here.

Comment: if `somethingElse.getUrl()` or `doc.toJSONString()` return `null` or anything that is not a `String` such as a `URI` since postForEntity has many overloads then it won't match.

Comment: This is the `postForEntity()` method I'm calling:  `public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(URI url, @Nullable Object request, Class<T> responseType)`

Comment: Updated for that, your mock was definitely mocking the `postForEntity` that uses a string as the first param.

Comment: No change.  `something.thatReturnsOAuth2RestTemplate(props)` is actually being called as well.. not sure what is going on.  Reading these answers on it though - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272391/mockito-mocking-resttemplate-postforentity

Comment: I have it working - you were right, it was a matching issue.  `when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(response);`.  If you could change your answer that would be great, I've accepted it :)